# Not showing dropdowns selected on the click on browser Back button

Tags: internet-explorer-11, back-button

We have a old asp site in which there iscomplicated search with many drop down controls in it. When the user fills in the criteria, searches and again wants to go back to the same criteria, he clicks the back button but for some reasons the criteria is lost. i.e. the drop downs are not loaded with the previous selection.

This works perfectly fine in old versions of IE. But not in IE 11.

The site is running under https. But i dont think that is a cause. Because the same thing works on IE 9.

Arun

Comment: Can you provide relevant portions of your code? It's essential for us to help you.

Comment: It is difficult but i shall try and get the code. But meanwhile, have we had any such instances or issues reported earlier?